# Trying to gather the environment variables of my linux envrionment, but I keep getting segmentation faults

Tags: c

Trying to print the environment variables, store them onto tokens, place said tokens into an array and then sort them with bubble sort.
So far, I cannot put them onto an array without experiencing a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
#define MIN 5


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
int i = 0;

char *delimiter;

delimiter= ".:;";

char *token;

char *tokenArray[50];


while(envp[i])
{
        //token = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        token = strtok(envp[i], delimiter);
        printf(" %s \n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        tokenArray[i] = malloc(50);
        strcpy(tokenArray[i], token);
        //free(token);
        i++;

}

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{

printf(" %s \n ", tokenArray[j]);
        free(tokenArray[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to see on which line the code crashes?

Comment: Do you understand how pointers and memory allocation work? More than once, you set a pointer to malloc(something), and then overwrite it in a subsequent line, thus leaking the memory.

Comment: I read at least five tutorials and this same point comes up MULTIPLE times. The tutorials ALL say that each time you call malloc, an address in memory gets allocated. Of course then I come to websites like Stack, and apparently it works differently, because calling malloc multiple times means apparently I'm overwriting the last memory call, and when I check the 'online tutorials' they never mention anything besides each malloc holds its own memory address.

Comment: Ok, let's take a small example then. If we take this code: `int x; x=5; x=3;` I assume that it is obvious that `x=5` has no effect whatsoever. It's nothing different with pointers.

Comment: So let me get this straight . . . .I shouldn't use malloc more than once without freeing it, because it's like overwriting x = 5 with x = 3, yes?

Comment: Sort of but not quite. Every malloc should have a free. But these two snippets are 100% equivalent: `char *p = malloc(1); p = "foo";`, `malloc(1); char *p = "foo";`. The call to malloc has no effect except causing a memory leak.

Comment: So, in calling something like malloc(1) I'm allocating 1 byte, what if I called malloc(20) after that before freeing malloc(1) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can make a million mallocs in a row before freeing. It's not about that. It's about reassigning pointers. In your code (before you edited it) you have no way of freeing the memory you first allocated in the declaration of delimiter. In the exact same way in my comment above, there is no way to retrieve the previous value of a variable.

Comment: Okay, so can you help me figure out where I went wrong with my new code, then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code that puts all the environment variables in `tokens`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    const char *delimiter = "=";

    // Calculate the number of env variables. This is much better than
    // assuming a maximum size.
    size_t no_env = 0;
    while(envp[no_env])
        no_env++;

    // Allocate space for no_env pointers
    char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(*tokens) * no_env);

    for(int i=0; i<no_env; i++)
    {
        // Token is not used outside this loop, so there's no point in declaring
        // it outside. Same goes for the indexing variable i.
        char *token = strtok(envp[i], delimiter);
        // Allocate space for the string
        tokens[i] = malloc(strlen(token) * sizeof(*tokens[i]));
        strcpy(tokens[i], token);
    }

    // Free all the strings and then the last pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < no_env; i++)
        free(tokens[i]);
    free(tokens);
}
```

Note that this code does not have proper error checking for the malloc calls. I could have included that, but that would complicate things quite a lot. In most cases, the operating system will take care of anything you have not `free`d when the program exits, but on some systems, it can be an issue. If you're coding for such a system, then it can look like this:

```
    // Like previous code before this

    int ret = 0;

    if (!(tokens = malloc(sizeof(*tokens) * no_env))) {
        ret = EXIT_FAILURE;  
        goto END;
    }

    // Now i has to be declared outside for later use
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<no_env; i++)
    {
        char *token = strtok(envp[i], delimiter);
        if(!(tokens[i] = malloc(strlen(token)))) {
            ret = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto FREE;
        }
        strcpy(tokens[i], token);
    }

    i--;
FREE:
    for(; i > 0; i--)
        free(tokens[i]);
    free(tokens);
END:
    return ret;
}
```

For your code, you will do just fine with a simple `if(!(p=malloc(...)) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }` instead of all these `goto` statements.

When using `malloc`, always use the form `p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * size)`. That significantly reduces the risk of errors. If you're allocating space for a string (char) then you can skip the `sizeof` and go directly on `p = malloc(size)` but make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Instead of a `strlen()`/`malloc()` pair please use `strdup()`. It does exactly what is needed and makes your intention much clearer.

Comment: @thebusybee I would if that function was a part of the standard, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

While it is quite unclear why you are tokinizing each environment variable with a `delimiter= ".:;";`, there is nothing wrong with it (I would add `"*"` as well). Instead of looping over the environment variables twice (once to count the number to allocate pointers, the next time to tokenize variables into individual tokens), you can simply iterate over `envp` once and `realloc` pointers as needed.

Start with some number of pointers (say `2`) and then compare your `used` pointers against  the number available (`avail`) and when they are equal, double the number of pointers available with `realloc`.

One other consideration. `strtok` modifies the original string when tokenizing. So instead of tokenizing `envp[x]` directly and thus modifying what is in `envp`, you can (optional) simply copy the environment before tokenizing the copy.

A short implementation that allocates and reallocates pointers, and then allocates storage for each token could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTRS 2     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 8192

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    size_t i = 0, used = 0, avail = NPTRS;  /* counters */
    const char *delim = ".:;*";             /* delimiters */
    char **tarray = NULL;                   /* pointer to pointer */

    /* allocate/validate NPTRS pointers initially */
    if (!(tarray = malloc (avail * sizeof *tarray))) {
        perror ("malloc-tarray");
        return 1;
    }

    while (envp[i]) {               /* loop over each env var */
        char envstr[MAXC];          /* array to hold current env var */
        size_t envlen = strlen (envp[i]);   /* get env var len */
        /* tokenize envp[i] */
        if (envlen >= MAXC - 1) {   /* check env fits in envstr */
            fputs ("error: envstr exceeds MAXC chars.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        /* strtok modifies original, make copy of env var before strtok */
        memcpy (envstr, envp[i], envlen + 1);
        /* tokenize env var based on delim */
        for (char *p = strtok (envstr, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
            size_t len = strlen (p);/* length of token */
            if (used == avail) {    /* check if realloc of pointers req'd */
                /* always realloc using a temporary pointer */
                void *tmp = realloc (tarray, 2 * avail * sizeof *tarray);
                if (!tmp) {     /* validate reallocation */
                    perror ("realloc-tarray");
                    goto done;  /* tarray still good, break nested loops */
                }
                tarray = tmp;   /* assign realloc'ed block to tarray */
                avail *= 2;     /* update avaialble no. of pointers */
            }
            /* allocate/validate storage for token */
            if (!(tarray[used] = malloc (len + 1))) {
                perror ("malloc tarray[used]");
                goto done;  /* goto req'd to break nested loops */
            }
            memcpy (tarray[used++], p, len + 1);    /* copy to new memory */
        }
        i++;    /* advance to next environment variable */
    }
    done:;

    for (i = 0; i < used; i++) {    /* output all tokens */
        printf ("tarray[%3zu] : %s\n", i, tarray[i]);
        free (tarray[i]);   /* free storage of strings */
    }
    free (tarray);  /* free pointers */

    (void)argc, (void)argv;     /* suppress unused varaible warnings */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/main_envp
tarray[  0] : XDG_VTNR=7
tarray[  1] : LESSKEY=/etc/lesskey
tarray[  2] : bin
tarray[  3] : MANPATH=/usr/local/man
tarray[  4] : /usr/share/man
tarray[  5] : /opt/kde3/share/man
tarray[  6] : NNTPSERVER=news
tarray[  7] : XDG_SESSION_ID=1
tarray[  8] : SSH_AGENT_PID=3195
tarray[  9] : KDE_MULTIHEAD=false
tarray[ 10] : HOSTNAME=wizard
tarray[ 11] : DM_CONTROL=/var/run/xdmctl
<snip>
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/main_envp
==16243== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16243== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16243== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16243== Command: ./bin/main_envp
==16243==
tarray[  0] : XDG_VTNR=7
tarray[  1] : LESSKEY=/etc/lesskey
tarray[  2] : bin
tarray[  3] : MANPATH=/usr/local/man
tarray[  4] : /usr/share/man
tarray[  5] : /opt/kde3/share/man
tarray[  6] : NNTPSERVER=news
tarray[  7] : XDG_SESSION_ID=1
tarray[  8] : SSH_AGENT_PID=3195
tarray[  9] : KDE_MULTIHEAD=false
tarray[ 10] : HOSTNAME=wizard
tarray[ 11] : DM_CONTROL=/var/run/xdmctl
<snip>
==16243==
==16243== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16243==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16243==   total heap usage: 292 allocs, 292 frees, 11,723 bytes allocated
==16243==
==16243== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16243==
==16243== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16243== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.